# Removing a bevel

Tags: bevel

Which technique would you suggest to remove this edge/ bevel?

[image: 3Dmodel]

Comment: Hello, hard to say, what does it give if you simply delete the faces? Maybe share your file?

Comment: It was a pricy model, so I can't repost, but I can screenshot in wireform if that helps? Deleting faces gets messy. Knife tool works slightly better. I'm also playing with some sculpting tools to see if I can just bring it down.

Comment: Yes please show the wireframe. I'm afraid sculpting won't work well...

Comment: You could strip out a tricky chunk, (perhaps including a corner, for example) and share that on https://blend-exchange.com/